# How to delete label on Kubernetes namespace

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I labeled a Kubernetes namespace like so:

```
kubectl label namespace kube-system name=kube-system
```

How do I get rid of this label?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use below command to remove the label

```
 kubectl label namespace kube-system name-
```